# percentile_approx not working on aggregate column over window

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, window-functions

I am trying to calculate 25 percentiles of aggregate column i.e., sum(sales) over a group of columns like store, dept

Below is the sample data

| store | dept | item | date | sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 01-01-2024 | 30 |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 02-01-2024 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 03-01-2024 | 50 |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 01-01-2024 | 30 |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 02-01-2024 | 5 |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 03-01-2024 | 50 |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 04-01-2024 | 10 |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 05-01-2024 | 60 |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 06-01-2024 | 70 |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 07-01-2024 | 60 |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 08-01-2024 | 70 |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 09-01-2024 | 60 |
| 1 | 4 | 1243 | 10-01-2024 | 90 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 | 01-01-2024 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 | 02-01-2024 | 50 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 | 03-01-2024 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 | 04-01-2024 | 50 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 | 05-01-2024 | 20 |
| 1 | 2 | 12 | 06-01-2024 | 50 |

---

I am trying to execute below code to calculate 25 percentiles of rolling aggregate sales by store and dept, but it fails. If I just calculate percentile_approx of column it works, but that is not what I want

```
w_30_dept = (Window()
     .partitionBy([col("store"),col("dept")])
     .orderBy(col("date").cast('long'))
     .rowsBetween(-7,-1))


df = df.withColumn('Q1',round(f.expr('percentile_approx(sum(sales), 0.25)').over(w_30_dept),2))
```

Any advice is greatly appreciated